# How to make Elmah work with UnobservedTaskException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, task-parallel-library, elmah

I'm developing a asp.net mvc application. The architecture of my application as below:

1. a DBAccessLayer     //layer for accessing database
2. a ServiceLayer        //layer to connect 1 and 3.
3. a WebLayer            //Web UI layer

I want to log all application exceptions including the exceptions  in the TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException event.

I've tested to do as below:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ...
    TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (object sender, UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs excArgs) =>
    {
      ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(excArgs.Exception);      
      excArgs.SetObserved();
    };
}
```

but when the UnobservedTaskException event is fired, the application crashed with exception as below:

```
    System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled
         Message=Value cannot be null.
         Parameter name: context
         Source=Elmah
         ParamName=context
    StackTrace:
         at Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromContext(HttpContext context) in c:\builds\ELMAH\src\Elmah\ErrorSignal.cs:line 67
         at MyMvcApplication.<Application_Start>b__0(Object sender, UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs excArgs) in ...\Global.asax.cs:line 82
         at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.PublishUnobservedTaskException(Object sender, UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs ueea)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExceptionHolder.Finalize()
```

Additionally, I put the UnobservedTaskException event in the global.asax.cs of WebLayer, can it be fired when the DBAccessLayer and ServiceLayer have unobserved exceptions?

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't directly answer your question, but we have code in our apps that attempts to get the current HttpContext.  If it succeeds, it logs via Elmah, otherwise it generates an email...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when your handler gets fired, there isn't an HttpContext because the scheduled task is not running as part of an HTTP request. Instead of using

```
ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise
```

you could use

```
ErrorLog.GetDefault(null).Log
```